# Multiple application authentication using one login

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I have an application running on asp.net with Identity for user management.

Now I am in production of another application having technologies asp.net core and Angular 7.

I have tried using same DB for both application for login but it didn't worked since Identity on .net and .net core have different Hashing algorithms.

can I use my .net app verification same for .net core and angular 7 app by just giving any Button link from the first application?

When I proceed like above i found some problems listing below:-

- How to avoid user directly accessing the second application .net core ?

How can i proceed with this scenario?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: You have an existing application with ASP.NET Identity (not Core) that will continue to exist, and now you want to create a new application using ASP.NET Core Identity and want to reuse the existing Identity database while keeping full compatibility with the old application? (i.e. both applications will co-exist)

Comment: Your best bet is to abstract the auth using a centralized auth provider like Identity Server, which can plugin to Identity setup. Then, everything just auths against that, and the underlying data store, or even that fact that Identity is utilized at all, is inconsequential.

Comment: @poke yes, same requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ASP.NET Core Identity uses a more secure hashing mechanism for the passwords, by default you cannot use an older ASP.NET Identity to access the same database since it doesn’t understand the new mechanism. What works out of the box however is to use ASP.NET Core Identity with old hashes since the hash is actually versioned to allow easy migration from an older database.

If you want ASP.NET Core Identity and ASP.NET Identity to co-exist using the same database, you will have to use the older hashing algorithm since that is the only one ASP.NET Identity supports. Luckily, you can configure ASP.NET Core Identity to only use that algorithm itself.

The configuration is explained [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#password-hasher-options) and looks like this:

```
services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(option =>
{
    option.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2;
});
```

This will effectively downgrade ASP.NET Core Identity to use the older algorithm, allowing full compatibility with ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the show here.

I discovered that if you upgrade a version 2.0 OWIN set up to version 3.0 that comes with .NET Core you can update the groups of tables for ver 2.0 manually to match version 3.0 fields and then perform an update query on AspNetUsers table to populate the new fields.

These being the email address and usernames that are now stored in block capitals and leave the existing fields as they were. There will be other fields in other tables that you’d need to add, but generally you will not require to put data in them, just make sure they are present.

The very good thing here is that when your existing users sign in for the first time on the new app using their existing credentials for the older version, .NET Core will automatically upgrade the password hash and the users will still be able to login to the new version 3.0 set up. This means no hassle for users and no loss of accounts for you.

This of course will only apply when you upgrade the older app to .NET Core or you use a single sign on web api or similar that speaks to the new ver 3.0 OWIN set up..

Just thought I would share this as I had to make this move to a new app but had existing 1,000+ users already registered on the old version 2.0 MVC 5 app.

Make sure you back up first as you cannot downgrade an account once you have signed in with the new version as ver 2.0 will not be able to read the new ver 3.0 password hash, it only works 2.0 > 3.0